# Create function that draws lines inside sub?

Tags: vb.net, user-interface

Good day,

I want to create a function that draws lines by taking specified points and creating lines from them. From my experience, it seems that functions cannot be declared inside subs which is a bit of a problem. I need the function inside a sub that has the e as painteventargs (PEA for now) quality so I can assign my graphics variable the "Create Graphics" value. I already tried running the code without create graphics, and nothing drew on the screen. If there is a way to somehow sneak a function into a sub, or even give something like a class or structure the PEA quality, The help would be greatly appreciated

Visual studio 2019 16.6.0

.NET Core 4.7.2

WinForms API

Comment: **Subs are functions** (in a computer-science sense), they're just functions that don't return anything. Why are you opposed to adding class-level functions (methods) to perform drawing? What UI framework are you using? WinForms, WPF/XAML, UWP?

Comment: What you think you need is not what you need. If you want to draw on a control then you ONLY do that in the `Paint` event handler or a method called from that event handler. You store the data that describes your drawing in one or more fields and then, when the `Paint` event is raised, you use the `Graphics` object provided  to draw whatever that data describes.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Overriding `OnPaint` is preferable to using a `Paint` event-handler.

Comment: @Dai, that depends what you're drawing on. If it's a custom control that you want drawn a particular way every time then yes. If it's a standard control on a form, e.g. a `PictureBox`, and the drawing is determined at run time then handling the `Paint` event is exactly what you should do. Even if it's the form itself, where you certainly could override the corresponding method, most people will still handle events, e.g. the `Load` even of the form.

Comment: For instance, if you are drawing lines then you might define a `Line` structure or class and then store a `List(Of Line)` in a field. In the `Paint` event handler, you can loop through that list and draw each line. [Here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?426684) is one I prepared earlier.

Comment: Maybe he means a lambda method?

Comment: I was gonna say you sure can declare a function inside a sub, or LINQ wouldn't be very useful..

Comment: I'm not sure what use a lambda expression would be in this case. A delegate for a named method, maybe, but the question is too vague to be able to tell for sure. Using a lambda expression to draw on a form or child control on a form sounds like over-engineering to me. It would be much easier to provide a specific solution if the OP could provide an explanation of a specific problem, rather than a vague solution to an even vaguer problem.